# CComModule UnregisterServer error?

Tags: c++, com, winapi

I have a CComModule that is calling RegisterServer (TRUE) on DllRegisterServer and UnregisterServer (TRUE) on DllUnregisterServer. The UnregisterServer is getting a 0x8002801C (Error accessing the OLE registry.) error and leaving around registery keys. I am using a Windows Server 2k8 R2 machine with UAC enabled. The components are x86 and I am using the 32 bit regsrv32.

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run Regsvr32.exe from a command prompt that's elevated to administrator (i.e. UAC disabled).  Make a shortcut on your desktop to "cmd.exe", right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Registration is currently running elevated.

Comment: Update your post to mention that.  It is such a perfect explanation for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ATL and VS2008 then you can register your COM object per-user which writes the necessary registry keys to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.  You register your object by passing a special user switch to `regsvr32`, e.g.:

```
regsvr32.exe /i:user /n yourobject.dll
```

COM servers can be registered with the `/RegServerPerUser` switch.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437450/windows-limited-user-installation).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting but the software I work on is meant to be used by multiple users. (And require local administration/elevation). HKCU would not work for me :(